# Attribute to suppress certain types of exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Is there any attribute that I can use, attached to the method definition, that will suppress any exceptions of a certain type originating in that method? e.g.

```
[SuppressException(typeof(TimeoutException))]
public void TroubleMethod()
{

}
```

So when there is a `TimeoutException`, it won't throw outside of `TroubleMethod`?

Comment: a bad idea, indeed. something is not right with the design if you want to suppress exceptions (without passing them over or handling them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exception handling around the entire method:

```
public void TroubleMethod()
{
    try {
        // ...
    } catch(TimeoutException) {
        // Throw away
    }
}
```

I don't think an attribute that does what you describe exists, though. If you want the debugger to step through your method, you can always use `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]`, but as for suppressing exceptions, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostSharp to do some tricky instrumentation to add such attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can get a bit closer to your attribute-like syntax with:

```
static void SuppressException<TException>(Action a) where TException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        a();
    }
    catch (TException) { }
}

 public void TroubleMethod()
 {
     SuppressException<TimeoutException>(() => {
     ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, but you can always do this:

```
public void TroubleMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // silly code goes here
    }
    catch() { }
}
```

A bad idea in almost all circumstances, though sometimes acceptable (rare).  Just make sure to leave a comment for future maintainers (this includes you).

Answer (score 0):

you could use try-catch to catch the exeptions and just ignore it or better you could respond to that exeption
check out the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)